# Show alert from UITableViewCell class - Objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to show alert with button in custom cell.
How can I do this in Objective C?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Googling this? "objective-c button tableview" provides lots of results that might help.

Comment: I know how add button but i can׳t show the alert

Comment: Oh ok. Well, this is an opportunity to help you with using StackOverflow as well then - to get a better response, try to ask as specific a problem as you can, and post some of your code. The mantra is that as you try to refine your question, you'll usually find the solution on your own. Have you searched specifically for showing an alert from a button press? Googling "UIAlert from UIButton" will probably deliver a solution.

Comment: You don׳t understand, I can׳t show alert because it׳s UITableViewCell class.

Comment: @user2254968 you have to set a delegate on tableViewCell to your viewController and in the viewController you show the alert

Comment: Ok, how I do this?

Comment: Actually, I do - I'm just trying to get you to do some more research on your own. This is a pretty well covered tutorial in a lot of places. Try https://www.raywenderlich.com for lots of beginner tutorials on topics just like this.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a `weak` instance of the *container* `View Controller` to the custom table view cell.
The cell will use this *passed-in* `View Controller` to show an `UIAlertController`. 
Some sample code to achieve this would look like:

```
// CustomTableViewCell.h

@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell 

@property (nonatomic, weak) __kindof UIViewController *controllerDelegate; // __kindof used to avoid importing the View Controller class, we only need a controller object & nothing else, hence using __kindof will suffice

@end

// CustomTableViewCell.m

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {    
        ...
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setControllerDelegate:(__kindof UIViewController *)controllerDelegate{

    _controllerDelegate = controllerDelegate;

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"This is an alert!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *cancelButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:cancelButton];

    UIAlertAction *proceedButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Proceed" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        ... // add custom actions on alert button tap here
    }];
    [alertController addAction:proceedButton];

    [_controllerDelegate presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end


// MyViewController.m

@interface MyViewController()
...
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:taskTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.controllerDelegate = self;

    return cell;         
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create one custom cell with Label and Button whatever you want to display in it.

**CustomTableViewCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnAlert;

@end
```

**CustomTableViewCell.h**

```
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Now, in your controller, you need to create table view and give your custom cell and bind the button method in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**.

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return 10;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static N

SString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomTableViewCell";

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.lblName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row];
    cell.btnAlert.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.btnAlert addTarget:self action:@selector(alertButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
}

-(IBAction)alertButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Button Clicked" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil] show];
}
```

Comment: @user2254968 Did you get your solution?